# After updating to Magento 2.2.6, the following error is output

Tags: upgrade, magento2.2.6

After updating to Magento 2.2.6, the following error is output.

Go to

> Backend> System> Permission (All Users)> Users

Clicking each line... etc. outputs an error.

The following is an error message.

> Exception # 0 (Exception): Warning: Illegal offset type in
>   /var/www/html/multistore/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Tabs.php
>   on line 306

Answer (score 2):

I am still debugging on my development server, so far I found that changing the file /vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Tabs.php - line 306

```
$grandPosition = $orderByIdentity[$tab->getAfter()]->getPosition();
```

to

```
$grandPosition = $orderByIdentity[(string)$tab->getAfter()]->getPosition();
```

resolved the issue for me.

**This is not a fix** as it involves editing the core magento files, but indicates that it could be an issue with an extension that adds tabs to the user view - if you have any extensions that add tabs to this view, you could try contacting the vendor or disabling the module.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I copied your code and solved it.

Comment: How can I find the affecting module?